# Error caused by executing an executable jar made by Apache Ant

Tags: java, apache, ant, build

I have created a Java application which has the following Apache Ant build file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<project name="GUI" basedir=".">

<property name="version" value="0.2"/>
<property name="bin.dir"                        value="${basedir}/bin"/>
<property name="gui_bin.dir"                    value="${basedir}/gui_bin"/>
<property name="src.dir"                        value="${basedir}/src"/>
<property name="jar.dir"                        value="${basedir}/jar"/>
<property name="images.dir"                     value="${basedir}/images"/>
<property name="user.properties"                value="${basedir}/user.properties"/>


<!-- ============ Clean target =================== -->
<!-- Delete output files and directories -->

<target name="clean" description="Clean the directory: build, ${gen-src.dir}*, ${test.report.dir}">
    <delete dir="${jar.dir}"/>
</target>


<!-- 
============ Compile target =================== 
-->
<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${gui_bin.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${gui_bin.dir}" classpath="${basedir}/EFCore-1.0.0.jar" fork="true">
    </javac>
</target>


<!-- 
============ Create Executable Jar target =================== 
-->
<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
        <jar jarfile="jar/UPHECGui.jar" basedir="gui_bin" includes="**/*.class">
            <fileset dir="${basedir}">
                <include name="images/**/; EFCORE-1.0.0.jar" />
                </fileset>
                <manifest>
                    <attribute name="Main-Class" value="eu.keep.uphec.GUI"/>
                    <attribute name="Class-Path" value="EFCORE-1.0.0.jar"/>
                </manifest>
                <filelist dir="${basedir}" files="user.properties"/>
        </jar>
    </target>

<!-- 
    ============ Run target =================== 
    -->
<target name="run" depends="jar">
    <java classpath="jar/UPHECGui.jar;EFCORE-1.0.0.jar" classname="eu.keep.uphec.GUI" fork="true">      
    </java>
</target>
```

The tasks execute successfully: the jar task creates the jar and the run task launches successfully the application. When I go and try to execute the jar in a command line with the following code:

```
 C:\UPHECGUI\GUI-Project\ java -jar jar/UPHECGui.jar
```

the application throws the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.class.NoClassDefFoundError: eu/keep/kernel/CoreObserver
at.............
...............
...............
Could not find the main class: eu.keep.uphec.GUI. Program will exit.
```

Now, the GUI class with the main method is exactly in the specified folder (the run task executes successfully with this parameter). 
Here is a screenshot of the folder where the application is based:

[image]

Can someone please tell me what's wrong with it? I spent hours trying to figure it out but nothing has come out yet :-(
An help would be highly apreciated, thanks!!!!

Comment: If your jar file doesn't define a classpath in the manifest it has no idea where classes outside of your own reside.

Comment: I have added <attribute name="Class-Path" value="EFCORE-1.0.0.jar"/> but still nothing. A practical example would be greatly apreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-jar` option uses the manifest of the jar to set the classpath. Since your application depends on the jar `EFCORE-1.0.0.jar`, this jar should be in the classpath specified in the manifest of your `UPHECGui.jar`.

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html for explanations.

Comment: Does this mean that I have add:
<attribute name="Class-Path" value="EFCORE-1.0.0.jar"/>
inside the manifest tags?

Comment: Yes. And the path of the core jar in the manifest is relative to the location of the executable jar. This means that in order to work as is, the gui and core jars must be in the same directory.